# Updating a controller from another controller Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have two controllers that are active on my page:

```
// For handling any changes made to the Recipe Window
      ctrl.controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', 'view_service', 'recipe_service', function($scope, view_service, recipe_service) {
          $scope.title = recipe_service.get_title();
      }]);

      ctrl.controller('setNameCtrl', ['$scope', 'view_service', 'recipe_service', function($scope, view_service, recipe_service) {
          $scope.titleSet = recipe_service.get_title();
          $scope.setName = function(){
              recipe_service.set_title($scope.titleSet);
              //view_service.set_view_url({url:"partials/typeWindow.tpl.html"});
          };
      }]);
```

Both controllers are pulling from this service:

```
serv.service('recipe_service', function(){
    var recipe = {
                        title:"ace",
                        type:"",
                        market:[],
                        attribute:[]
                        };

    return {
        get_title: function() {
            return recipe.title;
        },
        set_title: function(newTitle){
            recipe.title = newTitle;
        }      
    };
});
```

The second controller updates the "title" that the first controller is referencing. My problem is that once the second controller changes "title" in the service, the first controller is not updated to reflect the changes. What I am thinking that needs to happen is to some how refresh the first controller to pull in those new changes. Any suggestion on how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

```
// For handling any changes made to the Recipe Window
  ctrl.controller('recipeCtrl', ['$scope', 'view_service', 'recipe_service', function($scope, view_service, recipe_service) {
      $scope.curRecipe = recipe_service.recipe;
  }]);

  ctrl.controller('setNameCtrl', ['$scope', 'view_service', 'recipe_service', function($scope, view_service, recipe_service) {
      $scope.curRecipe = recipe_service.recipe;
      $scope.setName = function(){
          //view_service.set_view_url({url:"partials/typeWindow.tpl.html"});
      };
  }]);

serv.service('recipe_service', function(){

    return {
        recipe : {
                   title:"ace",
                   type:"",
                   market:[],
                   attribute:[]
                 },
        set_title: function(newTitle){
            recipe.title = newTitle;
        }      
    };
});
```

Using the same object throughout will work... this object can be defined in the service or you can use

```
 angular.module("myApp",[]).value("myObject","Shared Value");
```

then inject this into you controllers like

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("MyCtrl",function($scope,myObject){console.log(myObject)})
```

I also posted a plnkr a while back showing some of the options:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ABQsAxz1bNi34ehmPRsF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/UQgAC8bzcJkmsfCMyP84?p=preview